# How to load/Unload tile chunks faster(C#)

Tags: c#, performance, loading, tiles, chunks

Ok So basically in my game, The world is made out of tiles and the tiles are split into chunks(50x50 tiles and the tiles are 16x16) so the whole world isn't loaded in memory. The chunks are saved to files and only ones that are needed are loaded(ones on screen and 1 off-screen for each side of the screen(top, left, bottom, right)), and others are unloaded etc.. This all works fine however, When loading chunks that actually contain tiles the game logic freezes for quite a bit(you know to load the file?), Basically my question is how would I make my current methods faster, So there's little to no noticeable lag?

Basically each chunk just contains a 2D array of bytes, Containing the tile type rather than the actual tile class, And That byte array is saved to a file to later be loaded.
My chunk Loading/Saving functions:

Saving:

```
    public void SaveChunk(int cx, int cy)
    {

        String chunkname = "";
        chunkname = WorldChunks[cx, cy].X + "_" + WorldChunks[cx, cy].Y;

        FileStream fileStream = File.Create(Main.ChunkPath + "\\Chunks\\" + chunkname + ".chnk");
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
        String json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(WorldChunks[cx, cy].myTiles, Formatting.None);
        writer.Write(json);
        writer.Close();
    }
```

Loading:

```
    public void LoadChunk(int xx, int yy)
    {

        string chunkname = xx + "_" + yy;
        if (File.Exists(Main.ChunkPath + "\\Chunks\\" + chunkname + ".chnk"))
        {
            //If the chunk is not loaded, Create a new chunk and begin loading it's tiles.
            if (WorldChunks[xx, yy] == null)
            {
                WorldChunks[xx, yy] = new Chunk(xx, yy);
            }

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Loading chunk [" + xx + "," + yy + "]");
            Stream stream = File.Open(Main.ChunkPath + "\\Chunks\\" + chunkname + ".chnk", FileMode.Open);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;
            WorldChunks[xx, yy].myTiles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<byte[,]>(reader.ReadToEnd(), settings);
            stream.Close();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Chunk loaded.. [" + xx + "," + yy + "]");
            int x, y;
            for (x = 0; x < Main.ChunkSizeX; x++)
            {
                for (y = 0; y < Main.ChunkSizeY; y++)
                {
                    byte _Type = WorldChunks[xx, yy].myTiles[x, y];
                    int tx = (xx * ChunkSizeX) + x;
                    int ty = (yy * ChunkSizeY) + y;
                    if (_Type > 0)
                    {
                        if (Tiles[tx, ty] == null && tx < MaxTilesX && ty < MaxTilesY)
                        {
                            Tiles[x + (xx * ChunkSizeX), (yy * ChunkSizeY) + y] = new Tile();
                            Tiles[(xx * ChunkSizeX) + x, (yy * ChunkSizeY) + y].Type = _Type;
                            if (ty > GROUND_LEVEL[tx] + 1)
                            {
                                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Below level:" + x + "|" + tx);
                                Tiles[tx, ty].HasBG = true;
                            }

                        }
                        else continue;
                    }

                }
            }

        }

    }
```

I've tried changing the chunksize around, I've tried 25x25, 16x16, 35x35 etc etc.. But still to no avail.
So How could I make these functions faster? Any other tips/advice would be very much appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT: The bottleneck in my code going from stopwatch and other tests is the actual loading from the file I even removed the placing of the tiles and it still locked up the game logic however I realized the biggest noticeable delays are when I'm in-between chunks and it has to load more chunks than usual like so:
[image: Picturing showing when my game logic takes the biggest hit]

Now my may be chunks actually bigger than that, but that same thing is possible.

My save function simply saves 1 byte per tile, My file size is only 2.5kb or so per chunk, As there are 2,500 tiles per chunk and 1 byte per tile (just saves the type of tile).

So I didn't think saving and loading them would be much of an impact, I have setup an async filestream as well earlier on, But the performance was practically the same.

Here's my code for loading/unloading chunks:

```
    public void CheckChunks()
    {
        int StartX = (int)Math.Floor(ScreenPosition.X / (ChunkSizeX * 16)) - 2;
        int StartY = (int)Math.Floor(ScreenPosition.Y / (ChunkSizeY * 16)) - 2;

        if (StartX < 0) StartX = 0;
        if (StartY < 0) StartY = 0;

        int EndX = (int)Math.Floor((ScreenPosition.X + GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width) / (ChunkSizeX * 16)) + 2;
        int EndY = (int)Math.Floor((ScreenPosition.Y + GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height) / (ChunkSizeY * 16)) + 2;
        if (EndX > MaxChunksX) EndX = MaxChunksX;
        if (EndY > MaxChunksY) EndY = MaxChunksY;

        for (int x = StartX; x < EndX; x++)
        {
            for (int y = StartY; y < EndY; y++)
            {
                if (WorldChunks[x, y] == null)
                {

                    LoadChunk(x, y, true);

                    if (WorldChunks[x, y] != null)
                    {

                        LoadedChunks.Add(WorldChunks[x, y]);
                    }
                     break;
                }

            }
        }

            foreach (Chunk cc in LoadedChunks)
            {

                if (cc.X < StartX  || cc.Y < StartY || cc.X >EndX || cc.Y > EndY)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Chunk to be unloaded..");
                    ChunkBuffer.Add(cc);
                    UnloadChunk(cc);

                }
            }

            foreach (Chunk c in ChunkBuffer)
            {
                LoadedChunks.Remove(c);
            }
        ChunkBuffer.Clear();

    }
```

How do games like minecraft load and unload their chunks so quickly?

Comment: To make something faster you need to know what is slow in your code. Profile (or at least measure time with `Stopwatch`) and go from there.

Comment: Thank you for this, But I forgot to mention I've used stopwatch, And even removed parts just to see where the bottleneck was. It's with the actual loading from the file, However I'm not sure if it's with the Deserialize or the reading from the file(most likely reading). I will do further tests and see exactly where it is.

Comment: I too am making a similar game. May I ask what your "WorldChunks" is, I'm guessing a class? Also, how do you keep track of which chunks are loaded/unloaded? I'm using a List for this, but I was looking for the opinion of someone else working on something similar to see how they have done it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Disk operations would generally be too heavy to execute within a single game frame without visibly impacting the framerate. Your disk operations could run in a separate thread. You would need to make sure that the memory is locked appropriately while the loading is taking place. This could still result in a visible delay if the player happens to reach the edge of a chunk before the next chunk is finished loading e.g. what if the player is in the bottom corner of a chunk and then moves right and down at the same time into the unloaded diagonal chunk? This could be solved by loading the 4 adjacent chunks as well as the 4 diagonal chunks, and ensuring that the chunks are large enough that the player wont quickly reach the edge. If your not familiar with multi threading, some research is required.

http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/

Another possible approach is to split your game world into multiple maps and load a whole map into memory rather than smaller chunks. This takes longer to load but only needs to be executed when the player moves in between maps so generally has less impact on the player experience. Loading screens can be used here if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will definitely look into multi-threading! I have set up async loading for the chunks before, However there was no note able performance increase while using it, Maybe I was doing it wrong? But any idea how games like minecraft load their chunks so smoothly without major interruptions of game logic?(I'm assuming it uses Async to run the load functions on a different thread?)

Comment: Its hard to say but my guess would be that a resource was being locked which was required by the main thread. Is the memory for the current chunk separate from the adjacent chunks?

Comment: How big is the file in total? If its just a 2d array of tile id's, could the whole file be loaded?

Comment: Edited my main post, But yea the memory for the current chunk is separate from the adjacent, and the total file size of each chunk is ~2kb(1 byte per tile, 50x50 tiles per chunk).

Answer (score 1):

`LoadChunk` only does two things, disk IO and deserialization.  You can play around with trying to speed them up independently.  Depending on how much data you are loading, just adding a BufferedStream could help.  A totally different option would be to use asynchronous I/O.  It's a little harder to work with, but it won't block your UI thread and you'll get some easy parallelism.

I would not expect JSON deserialization to be the fastest, you should compare its performance with your own deserialization routine.

16 x 16 tiles seem pretty small, is there a reason not to make them bigger?  The bigger the tiles the fewer calls to LoadChunk.  And once you speed up loading as much as you can, you'll have a good idea when to load the next off-screen tile.  E.g. if it takes 3 "ticks" to load a tile you should load it when the player is within 3 squares of the edge.

`SaveChunk` can be moved to a ThreadPool thread or rewritten to use asynchronous IO.

Answer (score 0):

As the last comment said before, JSON deserialization is not the fastest way. You could try to use Binaries instead. This could speed up the process of deserialization.

```
Convert.ToString(myByte, 2).PadLeft(a, c);
```

where a is the amount of characters in the string and c is the char to fill up the rest unused space with.

In your case you can specify a to be 8 and c = '0'. this will work for a byte.